# How to serialize a JsonArray with C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

SO I have a `Json` array as following:

```
{[data, [{"name":"Micheal Jackson","pic_large":"https://scontent.x.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14909900_10154513795037597_3241587822245799922_n.jpg?oh=54ead7e0ba74b45b632d96da1515ccf8&oe=591C4938","id":"10154729171332597"}
```

How can I serialize it with C# to parse it into objects and then pass it to the view.

**EDIT:**

```
{[data, [{"name":"Sayed Zubair Hashimi","pic_large":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14909900_10154513795037597_3241587822245799922_n.jpg?oh=54ead7e0ba74b45b632d96da1515ccf8&oe=591C4938","id":"10154729171332597"},{"name":"Junaid Walizada","pic_large":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14055012_1760562554217155_4937121194048198140_n.jpg?oh=376b49c9d04c2676ebe3d853b122165e&oe=58EA033D","id":"1821833754756701"},{"name":"Mohib Akhondzada","pic_large":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/14264218_592094647641140_6351146344336469735_n.jpg?oh=a8a63893d71f76c45fa3d07389f1700a&oe=59147C84","id":"648198542030750"},{"name":"Za Beah","pic_large":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/15741112_359701871054520_6692094260041596196_n.jpg?oh=6d9a0e73f70145b821c79cbe738090a0&oe=58E5B5B5","id":"360411140983593"},{"name":"Baser Nader","pic_large":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/15094436_10153876544626432_1550234361821853528_n.jpg?oh=e197fa712b3180a20612ecdacb01747c&oe=58E54DEC","id":"10153975726331432"},{"name":"Abasin Deniz","pic_large":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/15698075_440749809647293_7905213567074684088_n.jpg?oh=aeb22664f458d75fc00638ca6fa4ecfc&oe=591F7BB3","id":"444098429312431"}]]}
```

**EDIT2:**
Here is how I retrieve above `Json`.

```
var appsecret_proof = access_token.GenerateAppSecretProof();

                var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);

               dynamic myFeed = await fb.GetTaskAsync(
                    ("me/feed?fields=likes{{name,pic_large}}")
                    .GraphAPICall(appsecret_proof));
```

Comment: What you have shown in your question is not valid JSON.

Comment: This is what I get from a facebook API call `me/feed?field=likes{name,pic_large}`. as far as you know faebook api calls always returned in Json.

Comment: Yes, I know very well that facebook always returns valid JSON. I didn't say the contrary. What I said is that what you posted in your question is not a valid JSON - that's not the same thing. So please update your answer by providing the exact JSON string you got from the API.

Comment: So what could be the result that facebook did not returned a valid json?

Comment: Look at what you posted in your question. Put it here: http://jsonlint.com/ and see that it is invalid. But even without a JSON validator you can see that your input is invalid, just count the number of opening braces and the closing braces and see that they don't match. Maybe you wrongly copy-pasted something, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Gives an Error on a field name `name`

Comment: Yes, now please show the real JSON you got from facebook if you expect to get some real answers.

Comment: Look at the question again I edited it with the complete set of Json array I checked it jsonlint.com it also gives an error

Comment: Yes, because it is still invalid :-)

Comment: Do you want me to show you how I retrieve this json array?

Comment: I have no idea where you are retrieving it from, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings shown in your question are all invalid JSON. A properly formatted JSON might look like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "Micheal Jackson",
        "pic_large": "https://scontent.x.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14909900_10154513795037597_3241587822245799922_n.jpg?oh=54ead7e0ba74b45b632d96da1515ccf8&oe=591C4938",
        "id": "10154729171332597"
    }]
}
```

Now if you want to map this to C# class that's pretty easy to do. Just define the models to reflect this structure:

```
public class Feed
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pic_large")]
    public string PicLarge { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public IList<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }
}
```

and then all that's left is to deserialize the JSON string using a JSON serializer such as [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) back to this object structure:

```
string json = ... the json string shown above
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
foreach (var feed in result.Feeds)
{
    Console.WriteLine(feed.Name);
}
```

Comment: I get an error of `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Facebook.JsonArray' to 'string'`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create class with properties same as in json and then use the following code :

```
class obj
 {
   public string name {get ; set; }
   public string pic_large {get ; set; }
   public id {get ; set; }
 }

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
.
.
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<obj>(jsonString);
```